# how to integrate spring session with spring saml?

Tags: spring, spring-saml, spring-session

I tried to integrate spring session with spring saml project, but unfortunately, I always failed. the reason I need to do this is I need to use clustered session, but spring saml by default does not allow that.

Also spring saml is using spring 3, but seemed spring session require 4.x.

Any idea to do this approach?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to show the things you tried, while you failed. That might make it easier to pick on, rather than starting from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using Spring SAML with openSAML, Spring Boot and Spring Session (Redis store) for integration with OKTA (the IdP). 
I'm not using clustering but everything else is fine. What issues are you getting exactly? I can send you a POM to show the versions i'm using etc if that's of interest.